# Heroku - No module named wsgi

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn

I followed the getting started Django guide on the Heroku support center but I am getting the following error when I try to start it on either Heroku or with foreman:

```
ImportError: No module named wsgi
```

Here is my procfile:

```
web: gunicorn testproject.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

Here is my django project settings file:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import os
oneyr = date.today() + timedelta(days=365)
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG')
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb'
USE_I18N = False
USE_L10N = True

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static/')
MEDIA_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static/'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testproject.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates')
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'gunicorn',
    'storages',
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
```

Does anyone have any idea why this app won't start?

Comment: For starters, you should change your Procfile to be:

`web: gunicorn testproject.wsgi -b $PORT`

Comment: Assuming django 1.4 as that is what is on the Heroku tutorial. Do you have a `wsgi.py` in your `/testproject/testproject/` dir?

Comment: Can you please mark the answer below as the accepted answer as it seems to have worked for a lot of people?

Answer (score 20):

This is an old question but I'm responding to it nonetheless as I faced this exact problem recently and the answer by [Intenex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674794/intenex) although helpful was not able to resolve my issue.

As pointed out by [Intenex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674794/intenex) you're probably missing the `wsgi.py` file. This could be because you've created your project using Django 1.3 or a previous version. Creating a project using Django 1.4 automatically creates the `wsgi.py` just like `manage.py`, `settings.py`.

Unlike what [Intenex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674794/intenex) has pointed out, here's what you should do. Assuming you're on Django 1.3 or earlier version, create `wsgi.py` file in the project directory (same directory as `manage.py` etc.) and add the following to your `wsgi.py` file:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

# This application object is used by the development server
# as well as any WSGI server configured to use this file.
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Note the difference in the last 2 statements compared to Intenex's answer.

With this you should be able to run `foreman start` with the following in your Procfile:

`web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi`

Comment: Your answer gave me an idea about how to solve this problem: In my Procfile without no format, I had to change `web: gunicorn web_application.wsgi` to `web: gunicorn my_project.wsgi`.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you don't have a wsgi.py module file in your project directory. If you started your project (with django-admin.py startproject project) with Django 1.3 or earlier, the wsgi file was not automatically created. You'll want to create it yourself following this guide:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/

As per the guide, put this in the file, making sure to change 'mysite' to your project name:

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

# This application object is used by the development server
# as well as any WSGI server configured to use this file.
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Also, as I didn't see this in your settings, you'll want to make sure your project directory is included in your Python path as per the last sentence here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/#running-django-in-gunicorn-as-a-generic-wsgi-application

Or else you'll run into the same problem I did:
[Python app import error in Django with WSGI gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660627/python-app-import-error-in-django-with-wsgi-gunicorn)

After that, everything should work without a hitch. Cheers!

Sidenote: You might already be able to run gunicorn by changing your Procfile to:

```
web: python manage.py run_gunicorn
```

as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/#using-gunicorn-s-django-integration, but I haven't tested this myself so not sure. Might still need the wsgi.py module.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this problem; occured to me that my Procfile had Windows Format EOL Encoding; switched to UNIX EOL - and voilà, worked.

Comment: Use an editor of your liking (e.g., [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.6.8.html) on Windows), and change the "end of line encoding".

Answer (score 1):

Came across this error and the above question just now.

Found the settings file had a syntax error in the line for `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. The above descriptions help point me in that direction (at least looking at the settings).

Thought it might help somebody else out...

Answer (score 1):

I had this error as well, and the other solutions did not fix it. 
The source of my problem was that I had installed gunicorn through apt-get. To solve, I removed gunicorn via apt and ran `pip install gunicorn`.

Comment: This helps. Who could have thought that would be the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error because I manually renamed my project folder from `myproject` to `myproject_django`, but I didn't fix all of the references in the settings file. In particular,

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'
```

needed to be changed to

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject_django.wsgi.application'
```

Again, there a few references in that file that need to be changed. Just do a search and a careful, one-by-one replace.