# gunicorn fails to find wsgi file in django project

Tags: python, django, wsgi, gunicorn

I followed the tutorial [here](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/) to deploy django with gunicorn, nginx and supervisor.

My django project is originally from 1.3.x but now running under 1.4.10. I created a wsgi.py file in the django project directory.

I can successfully start gunicorn by calling: `manage.py run_gunicorn`

When I do this, the site runs perfectly fine.

However when I run `gunicorn mydjangoapp.wsgi:application` from within my django app's directory I get an error stating that mydjangoapp.wsgi could not be found.

If I change the command to `gunicorn wsgi:application` It locates the file but gives me an error that it can't find the mydjangoapp.settings file listed in wsgi.py.

However, if I change this settings path to be just "settings", then I get a different error message stating it can't find mydjangoapp.urls.

When I run `gunicorn mydjangoapp.wsgi:application` from one directory above my django app, I do not get an immediate error, but if I visit the site, I get an internal server error stating that one of my sites middleware dependencies could not be found.

Any thoughts why this is happening?

The error listed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660627/python-app-import-error-in-django-with-wsgi-gunicorn?rq=1) is almost identical to the error I get when I run the command outside of the directory. However, I tried the solution accepted there, and it did not work.